# When I enter text to individual ttk.entry every other ttk.entry in the array changes to the same value. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I enter text to individual ttk.entry every other ttk.entry in the array changes to the same value. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my simplified code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("test")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))


text = [StringVar()]*3
textbox = [None]*3
for x in range(1, 3):
    textbox[x] = ttk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable=text[x])
    textbox[x].grid(column=1, row=x, sticky=(W, E))
text[1].set("1")
text[2].set("2")

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to simply not use the `textvariable` option. It's completely unnecessary unless you plan to do variable tracing. Are you going to be using variable tracing?

Comment: I don't think so. I got the initial code from a tutorial and have tweaked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that you aren't initializing `text` properly. If you look closely you'll see that your list contains three references to a single instance of `StringVar`.

One solution, then, is to properly initialize the list. For example:

```
text = [tk.StringVar() for i in range(3)]
```

Another solution is to simply not use `StringVar` and `textvariable`. The `textvariable` attribute is optional in most cases. The only time you need to use `textvariable` is when you want to link two or more widgets together, or when you want to put a trace on a variable. Since it looks like you are doing neither of those, I recommend simply not using the `textvariable` option.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the list of `StringVar`s you are creating a list containing 3 references to the same instance.

```
>>> vals = [tk.StringVar()] * 3
>>> vals
[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x7f0623fcfa90>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x7f0623fcfa90>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x7f0623fcfa90>]
```

Note that the addresses are identical. You want 3 different instances. For instance:

```
>>> [tk.StringVar() for x in range(0,3)]
[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x7f06213105f8>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x7f0621310668>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x7f0621310710>]
```

Would do. As you have a single instance, all the widgets reflect the value of that one instance. If you use separate StringVar instances you will get a different value for each widget.

Comment: Thanks. I've been beating my brains out for days over this.